# Optimize way to normalize XML

Tags: java, xml, performance, xml-parsing

What is the best and optimized way to normalize XML in java?

We are persisting XML in Database and before persisting XML to DB, we want to normalize it, remove indentation and persist the whole XML as a single line as original XML is taking a lot of space. We are using Java Document Builder currently to remove indentation and under heavy load, document builder is taking a lot of memory and causing high CPU.

We persist different types of XMLs to db and some of ours XMLs are huge enough. Here is the sample snippet we are using. Any suggestions on how we can optimize it?

```
ByteArrayInputStream payloadStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(payload.getBytes(XML_ENCODING));

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);

DocumentBuilder dBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(payloadStream);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

Transformer trans = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, STRING_YES);
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, STRING_NO);
trans.setOutputProperty(INDENT_PROP, INDENT_AMOUNT);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
String xmlString = sw.toString();
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Document Builder, use a [StAX or SAX](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/SJSXP2.html) parser. They need hardly any memory as they don't build any model. You get an element and you write it out.

Instead of (or in addition to) space removal and normalization, consider compression. It makes the document much smaller and the const of indentation is close to zero.

I personally, find SAX simpler to use than StAX (though the majority would disagree). You extend a `DefaultHandler` with a couple methods like in [this example](https://dzone.com/articles/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and). As you don't care about the content, all you need is writing it out, e.g., using an `XMLStreamWriter`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will try to use stax.

Comment: I am looking for sample code. Please point to it if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a streaming XSLT 3.0 transformation that simply does

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:mode on-no-match="deep-copy" streamable="yes"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. We don't have option to use XSLT 3.0 and also we have to use SAXON-HE.